General formula for beta function type integrals
What if instead of xⁿ(1-x)ˢ, we had xⁿ(n-x)ˢ and the limits were 0 to n instead of 0 to 1?
Could we develop a general formula for such a case? In the former case we can write the answer as n!s!/(n+s+1)!, but can anything be done about the latter?
I once had a question in an exam where I had to integrate (3-x)²⁵x² from 0 to 3. I know this is easily integrable by using the King's rule, however, I was wondering if anything similar to the beta function could be done for this as well
Thank you

If $n$ and $s$ are positive integers, one is simply done by using the binomial theorem and then integrating term by term, or as you said king's rule. If you use newton's generalised binomial theorem, you should be able to express the generalised integral as an infinite sum of incomplete beta functions

See this - https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html, basically you won't get to see a particularly nice closed form as the regular beta function

@Kraken directly using binomial isn't always feasible if I have higher powers (such as x²⁵(5-x)⁶⁷ from 0 to 5). Thank you for the link, I'll check it out. I had never heard of incomplete beta functions yet  thank you

@AmrutAyan thank you for the response

Under $u=\frac{x}{n}$ the integral becomes :
$$\int_0^1(nu)^n(n-nu)^sn du=n^{n+s+1}\int_0^1u^n(1-u)^s du$$
This integral is precisely the beta function $B(n+1,s+1)$ so we have :
$$\int_0^nx^n(n-x)^s dx=n^{n+s+1}\operatorname{B}(n+1,s+1).$$
Using this
$$\int_0^3x^2(3-x)^{25}=3^{28}\operatorname{B}
(3,26)$$

Oh hey, that makes sense - thank you!
